# Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined on class Cart

Tags: javascript, typeerror, slice

I have a problem with some class for cart , which I must use in my work.
Here is code of this class:

```
class Cart {
  constructor() {
    this.key = "IT_SPA_CART";

    if (!this.exists()) {
      this.setItSpaCart([]);
    }
  }

  get() {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    return cookies.find(cookie => cookie.startsWith(this.key));
  }

  exists() {
    return this.get() !== undefined;
  }

  getItSpaCart() {
    const cookieValue = this.get().slice(12);
    const parsedValue = JSON.parse(cookieValue);

    return parsedValue;
  }

  setItSpaCart(value) {
    const stringifiedValue = JSON.stringify(value);
    document.cookie = `${this.key}=${stringifiedValue}`;
  }

  add(item) {
    const cartValue = this.getItSpaCart();
    this.setItSpaCart([...cartValue, item]);
  }

  remove(item) {
    const cartValue = this.getItSpaCart();
    const itemInCart = cartValue.findIndex(val => val.name === item.name);

    if (itemInCart !== -1) {
      cartValue.splice(itemInCart, 1);
      this.setItSpaCart(cartValue);
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to use this class, e.g. with method add(), like this:

```
let cart = new Cart();
cart.add([{ num: 1, cost: 2 }, { num: 3, cost: 4 }, { num: 5, cost: 6 }]);
```

this error occur:

*Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined at Cart.getItSpaCart*

Why this is happend?

Thanks for every hint.

Comment: `cart.get` returns `undefined`, perhaps `cookie.startsWith(this.key)` is not found ..?

Comment: When I run ' console.log(cart);' then on console, I have: 'Cart {key: "IT_SPA_CART"}', but in section 'Application' on console in Cookies there is nothing ...

Comment: Yes, `key` property in the object exists, but the cookie can't be found, it doesn't exist, or is a HTTPOnly (should be still seen in the DevTools), which can't be read by JS. But we can't give an answer of why the cookie doesn't exist ...

Comment: I changed this line: return cookies.find(cookie => cookie.startsWith("IT_SPA_CART"));

Comment: Now is working - strange ...

Comment: I made a [simplified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9k0awm8/) to demonstrate the code. It should work as it is, as long as the cookie really can be read.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ;-) Maybe You already know how to fix it, but if not, perhaps solution is changing code in this line: `const cookies = document.cookie.split(";");`. I changed ("; ) into ("; ").

Comment: Hi, thanks for this tip, but in my code i have code like this: `const cookies = document.cookie.split(";");` In my case the problem was with change the name of key when the key was not first in cookie file. Before key name white space is set.